# Inserting class object to binary tree

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I have an Employee class object with different variables within which I want to store in a templated binary tree but couldn't get it to work.

How do I insert an object into a templated binary tree?

I read somewhere and applied this but it isn't working..

```
Employee empObj; // empObj has sever variables within
BinaryTree<Employee> tree; // For normal value input, BinaryTree<int> works fine. but..

BinaryTree<Employee>::TreeNode<T> node; //Tree node is the struct class with the class template
node.value = empObj; // I don't actually have the function value. Is it preset?
tree.insertNode(empObj); // Nor do I have insertNode.
```

Note that my binary tree has two templated classes that are in their own header files (e.g. DerivedBinaryTree.h and BaseBinaryTree.h via inheritance) and has been tested to work fine with by inserting normal values.

The derived class contains the actual virtual functions implementations within the main Btree class, hence two btree classes.

The BinaryTree class mentioned above in the codes is actually the derived class, meaning that struct TreeNode is not within this class but rather the base class. Was wondering if this affects? If not, hope you can advise.

My main problem is trying to insert an object in the binary tree, normal values worked fine. The code above is tested on the test file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you paste in header file declaration of `insertNode`. It is likely it is requesting you add a node wrapper. Im not sure why `TreeNode` requires a type after.

Comment: What is the compile error?

Comment: I don't actually have the function insertNode. I only saw this else where and tried to apply it as I thought it was a possibility, perhaps you can share the actual code for this?

Comment: Ah take a look here: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/92192/

Comment: The code there is wrong as it is a template class and all the parts need to be in the header.

Comment: Hi, my 2 binary tree templated files are already in their own header files, do read the above on what I have added. Thanks!